# SQL Server concurrent inserts with bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, database, columnstore

I´m facing a lot of problem with processes blocked on concurrent inserts.

[Example of process status - sp_who2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZpFH.png)

Actually I have 5 services for import data from csv´s to the table (PosImport). The table has a key "idcountry" and each service import data for only one country.

For example:

- Service_BR_import: to import Brazil data
- Service_AR_import: to import Argentina data

[Image from the service code app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TKxD.png)

I read some articles about partition table (in this case by idcountry) to avoid this blocks, but I'm not sure if this is the best way.

ps: The table has a clustered column store index

Edited:
The other situation that I have is blocks in delete:

[Image of blocks in concurrents delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i895M.png)

In this case is running 2 deletes for differente countries (18, 47). I can split this table in 2 tables but it seems not the correct way.

Whats is the best way to avoid this blocks, Is using transaction with isolation level? Is partitioning the table? Is splitting the table in 2 tables?

Comment: Yes, you can use partitioning to avoid blocking. It all depends how much data you need to import, how long it takes. What problems are you experiencing with your current solution?

Comment: tks for quick answers. The importation is fast, aprox. 80.000/min, the main problem is the blocks. The importation is a win service app that make a download from remote dir and then import the file. In this moment I have 5 services working parallel downloading data from 5 different remote dir (countries) and importing in the same table. (here the errors occurs)

Comment: If performance is not a problem, is it not simpler to queue the table loads, i.e. run them one after another?

Comment: Looking at the screenshot I'm guessing that all processes were waiting for dbccFileCompact before 106 was killed. Shrinking files on columnstore index is extremely slow and locks data.

Comment: yes you´re right, I running a kill. But I´m just running a kill because I had a lot of blocked and I tried to stop all. In the normal process (without killed/rollback) I have a lot problem of blocks.

Comment: How many rows you insert in a single insert? It should be always more than 102,400. Could you also post output of the following query: select * from sys.dm_db_column_store_row_group_physical_stats where object_id = object_id ('your table') order by created_time desc